# noise calculation matlab data

Tags: image, matlab, noise

I have created code in matlab that adds noise to a dataset (size=3600,350):

```
data_noise=data+0.015*max(max(data))*randn(3600,350);
```

Now I want to calculate the noise percentage over the total data. I know the noise is 1.5% of the MAXIMAL value of the data, but that doesn't tell me the overall noise percentage.
Everything I tried tells me a noise percentage of ~2%, but if I look at the images, I have a lot more noise (matlab command for the plot below):

```
figure;plot(t(1258,:)); hold on; plot(data(1258,:),'k')
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edzxe.png]

Anyone that can help me?

Comment: Have you tried doing `(t-data)./t`?

Comment: Then I get a matrix (3600x350) of which the sum is 7.68.10^30. Or what should I do with it then?

Comment: The noise has a _standard deviation (or RMS value)_ equal to 1.5% of the maximal value of your data. But actual noise samples may be larger, in absolue value, than the standard deviation. In fact, that will happen about 30% of the time (`(1-normcdf(1))*2`)

Comment: It was pseudocode. Are you asking how to program something or you are just lost in what to do?

Comment: Well, I just want to know the global noise percentage of that dataset. But I really can't seem to find it..  
And yes, I am lost :(. If I could get a formula somewhere, that would help me a lot already (programming wise, I'm quite ok :p)

Comment: I think that you should do a fourier transform before adding noise. It is kind of hard to tell what the noise is since you have not defined the **maximum value** in the intended domain. Normally you talk about noise power, which which is the variance of the fourier transform of the data. So to say **Y(w) = F(w) + sigma^2** assuming white noise. Other than that, I do not think that the data looks so bad considered that the noise is very low in for some of the peaks. As louis mend said the noise probably have a standard deviation that is 1.5 percent of the maximum value.

Comment: It is sure the noise has a standard devation of 1.5% of the maximum value of my data.  
What if I do this, you think this will help:
    `sum(sum(abs(data-t)))/sum(sum(abs(t)))`

This gives me ~17%

Comment: I do also want to add that you only have plotted one dimension of the data. This is about 1/36% of all the samples. Try to do the calculation in two steps: 1) store the noise in a separate matrix (let's call it noise) 2) add `noise` to `data` (`data_noise = data+noise`). This will give you access to the noise data as well. Then, plot the noise data over `max(max(data))` in a surf plot (or in a "bin plot", using a colormap as well, this requires more job but looks nicer). This will give you a look on how the noise looks.

Comment: The noise has been plotted in 2 dimensions of the data (this is done by the `randn(3600,**350**)` command. I just showed you a plot of a 1D part of the spectrum to show you what the noise looks like.

Comment: @user3365108 no sum will probably not work. The noise may be really high for some samples if you are unlucky. If you want to check numerically, do a cdf (use `cdfplot`). The standard deviation is approximately at 0.25 and 0.75. Since the average is 0 you can easily read the standard deviation. This should be 1.5%. Also `randn` does not plot so no it is not done by `randn(3600,**350**)`